# Error in calling CMIS Query if String contains single or double quote

Tags: java, liferay, alfresco, cmis

Here's my problem: When I try to pass a query string in CMIS Query that contains single or double quotes it doesn't execute and gives an error as below:

```
06:19:23,306 ERROR [DispatcherPortlet:561] Could not complete request
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: Internal Server Error
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:506)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:661)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.DiscoveryServiceImpl.query(DiscoveryServiceImpl.java:179)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl$6.fetchPage(SessionImpl.java:935)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.AbstractIterator.getCurrentPage(AbstractIterator.java:132)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.AbstractIterator.getPageNumItems(AbstractIterator.java:57)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.AbstractIterable.getPageNumItems(AbstractIterable.java:86)
at com.zeetv.util.UtilMethods.getQueryResults(UtilMethods.java:349)
at com.zeetv.action.twitter.TwitterController.checkTitle(TwitterController.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:369)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.doHandle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:356)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handleResource(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:302)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doResourceService(DispatcherPortlet.java:859)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:527)
at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.serveResource(FrameworkPortlet.java:479)
```

Here's my query string:

```
select * from my:content where cmis:name Like 'test's new content1'
```

I've also tried like this:

```
select * from my:content where cmis:name Like '"test's new content1"'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to use the OpenCMIS QueryStatement class (https://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.13.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/QueryStatement.html). It does all the escaping for you.

Comment: As you tag this with "Liferay": Is this related to Liferay's CMIS store or a query that you execute yourself towards Alfresco that just happens to be within a Liferay application?

Comment: @OlafKock yes, I am calling alfresco from liferay.

Comment: @FlorianMüller thanks for the help. It worked with QueryStatement. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider reviewing [this](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Query_Language#Literals) :

> String literals are enclosed in single quotes. Escaping does not follow SQL-92 escaping. Two single quotes within a string literal do not represent a quote character: `''''` is not a single quote literal.
>
> CMIS defines backslash-based escaping with the available escape characters, determined by context.
>
> `'bob\'s'      is used in place of           'bob''s'`
>
> `SELECT * from cmis:document WHERE cmis:name = 'bob\'s'`
>
> Basic escaping:
>
> - `\\ represents \`
> - `\' represents '`
>
> ...